# how to use used hard drive into computer and make it work

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop

a have a Dell inspiron 17 laptop and the hard drive is broken, I also have a asus computer that is broken but the hard drive is ok. I put the asus hard drive in my Dell computer, but it doesn't work, understandably, How do I wipe everything of the hard drive, set it up and make it work, I dont have any cd´s with any softwares or programs.  sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Thanks.

Comment: "it doesn't work" – BIOS/UEFI doesn't see the disk? Or it does but any OS (e.g. live CD Linux) doesn't? Or maybe you mean OS from the disk just doesn't start?

Comment: the disk in the Dell computer has asus programs on it,  when I turn on the computer it shows text "no bootable devices"

Comment: Do you have any 8gb or larger USB drives?

Comment: What do the (dell's?) boot/bios settings say about which devices to boot? Might need to go there & tell it to look at the new hard drive. Or there might be a button to get a one-time boot menu

Comment: i have 8 gb usb

Comment: ok.  I got into the computer, I went to bios legacy and got into the windows, I think the windows is running in save mode or somethink

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the hardware matches so that the used hard disk does indeed connect and power, you will still need *something* in order to perform a new system install.

Probably the easiest is to get a Windows system disk. Windows 10 Home costs around $120 CAD for either a CD or USB disk. When you insert the disk and reboot the computer from its inoperative state, all you have to do is to follow the instructions and answer some basic questions.

Now, you can get Linux instead and that is fine. Linux disk images, either CD or USB, should be free to download but since your computer is not working, you will need to ask someone you know to get it and burn a DVD or USB key for it. The one I use is [OpenSUSE](https://software.opensuse.org/distributions/leap) with the installer fits on a DVD or USB key. Then, it's pretty much the same thing, you boot the machine and follow the prompts, except there are more questions and options and not as complete hardware support but it costs at most $0.50 since all you need is a blank DVD.

Comment: The easiest quick test is to get a Linux install CD or USB, e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After running from the USB without installing on the HDD, you then have the option to partition the disk as needed. Then you can install Linux if you like it, or download a Windows ISO and install that.